# Is userDefaults any worse performance than writing to a file? And how bad is that?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm receiving crash reports in Xcode that so far aren't very helpful.  I've updated my app to detect when the app crashes, and ask the user to tell us what happened when the app crashed.

That said, I'm toying with storing off the last method 'entered' in userDefaults so that I can include that in their email.... but don't want to slow the app to a crawl. Because I'm trying to detect what started before a crash, I'd need to do a synchronize too... or I'll lose the update. At the start of each method, I'd need to write out the class & method to userDefaults & sync. I'd be overwriting the same "LastMethod" key each time, not keeping multiple values.

Thoughts or alternatives?

Comment: It is better to save it directly to a file but in your case the difference won’t be noticeable.

Comment: There is absolutely NO performance issue, whatsoever.  It is an absolute non-issue, performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

I save a couple of Int and Double arrays to userDefaults every second (autosave function) in my game and on iphone 11 works great.

Launch of the application takes a second so it can be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

- UserDefaults can save integers, booleans, strings, arrays, dictionaries, dates and more, but you should be careful not to save too much data because it will slow the launch of your app. So **you should not save big data**
- There is also synchronize() method to force your data to save but Apple says we should not use.

Comment: This would be just a small string, maybe 50-180 chars.  Not a lot of data.  The only reason I believe I'd need synchronize() is to force the save *in case* the app crashes. if the data doesn't save and it crashes, then the whole effort is meaningless.